# How to add IK hands to very simple model?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, armature

I have a simple robot model here and it's split into 4 separate pieces. The head, body, and 2 hand nubs. I want the hands to be more independent so when I rotate the body bone the hand bones don't rotate/move around with it.

So I tried making an IK rig but I couldn't get it to work right because the model only had a few bones. What should I do to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77RvfjaWvRQ